# Checking between the date of revision and the date of the training

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I always have a problem in my checking...If a motorbike is in `revision` on `06/09/2019` to `11/09/2019` for the motorbike `000001`.

[image]

In my form `Training`, I can add the same motorbike on `07/09/2019`

[image]

Normally it's impossible

I have this:

```
$conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
        ->first();  

        $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();

        $conflictFormer = Training::where('fk_former', $fk_former)  
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();  

        $conflictMotorbike = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->first();  


        if(isset($conflictTraining)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate ! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflictRevision)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'The motorbike is in revision! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflictFormer)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate former ! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflictMotorbike)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate motorbik ! ');
        }
```

Do you have an idea please?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are querying against the **Revision** model and checking to see if the *time* is available at 10:00.  It is - the revision doesn't start until 12:00.  The time check on the **Revision** is constraining the query - you are only checking to see if something conflicts between 12:00 and 16:00, *regardless of the day*.  IE because it fails the query on the time (10:00 !== 12:00), it can't get a match, thus no `$conflictRevision`.

For a quick fix demonstration, remove the time check in the query: it should now show duplicate/conflict:

```
 $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
    ->first();
```

You have run into a bit of a logic problem.  Because your Revision can be over a period of days, and not just one day, how can you determine if the conflicting time is on the same day as when the user wants to schedule a training?  It doesn't make any sense to add a time of revision if the revision can be down for more than one day.  What day are we talking about it being down between 12:00 and 16:00?

I would suggest that you remove the time from the revision - it doesn't make sense from a logic standpoint to try to compare against a time if we don't know which day that specific revision time is for.

An exception to this would be if you are saying the revision is down EVERY DAY for 12:00 until 16:00.  If this is some type of schedule where the bike goes in only at 12:00, and is available up until 12:00 EVERY DAY, then having the hours in the revision is solid logic, *but that means the query in your question that is allowing the training... is correct* (the bike is in revision that day, but not until 12:00).

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, I'll delete the hours it's going to be easier. thank you very much for your explanations

Comment: I still have a little worry, can you help me when you have the time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835970/checking-between-seance-and-payment