# checking between seance and payment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Edit: **(08/09/2019)**

I have a question concerning the payment verification.

For example, the student `Leonard` pays a training on `09/09/2019` **only**.

[image]

In my form `Training`, I see that I can add several seances (trainings) ????

[image]

Can I block this?

For information, in my table `Training`, I have 5 foreign keys `(fk_former, fk_student, fk_motorbike, fk_typetraining, fk_payment)`.

[image]

To join the table training and payment I do this:

Model **Training**

```
class Training extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['date_seance', 'hour_start', 'hour_end', 'fk_motorbike', 'fk_former', 'fk_student'];
    protected $dates = ['date_seance'];

    public function motorbikes(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Motorbike', 'fk_motorbike');
    }

    public function formers(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Former', 'fk_former');
    }

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_student');
    }

    public function payments(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Payment', 'fk_training');
  }


}
```

Model **Payment**

```
class Payment extends Model
{

    protected  $fillable = ['date_payment', 'fk_student', 'method_payment',  'fk_type_seance', 'number_seance',  'total', 'fk_training']; 
    protected $dates = ['date_payment'];


    public function students(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_student');
    }


    public function trainings(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Training', 'fk_training', 'id');
    }
```

My relationships are ok

[image]

[image]

I have to do how to limit the trainings? Because it's for now illimited... the number of seances is not taken into account with the payment.

**Here is my function store() on my Controller Training** Edit

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
                'fk_former' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required'


        ]);


    $date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); 
    $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
    $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
    $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
    $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
    $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');



    $PaymentHasBeenMadeForThisTraining = Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student) 
    ->where('fk_training', $request->get('fk_training')) 
    ->first(); 

    $trainings = Training::with('payments')->get();

    $johnsTrainings = Training::with(['payments' => function($query) use($fk_student){
    $query->where('fk_student', $fk_student);
    }])->get(); 


    /*
    if(isset($trainings)){
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
        ->with('error', 'Duplicate ! ');
    }*/


    if(isset($johnsTrainings)){
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
        ->with('error', 'Limit ! ');
    }

        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
        }

    }
```

In testing your code I get this:

[image]

Comment: What is a `seance`?

Comment: @levi: Hello a training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several things which need attention.    You state:

> In my form Training, I see that I can add several seances ????

So I assume you want to link the ability to add trainings based on if a person pays for THAT training.  And on your form, you see that someone can add more trainings, even though they haven't paid for them.  And this is the problem.

I suggest you may wish to change your architecture on this and *simplify* your relationships.  If you create a payment as a one-to-many relationship between **Payment** model and **Training** model, you don't have to worry about checking to see if the payment can apply to many dates.

So on your **Training** model the relationship is many:

```
public function payments(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Payment", 'your_foreign_key', 'your_local_key');
}
```

And on your **Payment** model it has one Training only:

```
public function training(){
   return $this->belongsTo("App\Training");
}
```

You'll have to tweak this code and maybe a tiny bit of the database (probably don't need `fk_type_seance`, but do need some kind of `fk_training`).  But now it is very easy to check if you have a conflict for the payment of the training for this person by checking the payment against the specific **Training**.

```
$PaymentHasBeenMadeForThisTraining = Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student)  
    ->where('fk_training', $request->get('fk_training')) 
    ->first();
```

The if-check is now looking to see if the payment fits the training and the student - if so, it will stop a double payment for the same training by the same person.

For your list of trainings you'll need to come at this from the reverse.   Pull the trainings with payments:

```
 $trainings = Training::with('payments')->get();
```

Then, in your list, if you are listing a *specific person* you will need to check if the payment has been made by that person in order to list that person's payment for this specific training.  You'll have to work on this, but something like this in your controller:

```
 $thisStudentsTrainings = Training::with(['payments' => function($query) use($fk_student){
        $query->where('fk_student', $fk_student);
    }])->get();
```

**EDIT**: 
From here, check to see if the training from the form is in that collection of paid for trainings from this student (from the form):

```
$hasPaidForThisTraining = $thisStudentsTrainings ->contains('id', $request->get('fk_training'));
```

You may also have success by just pulling John's *payments* and then linking to the **Training** models within each - you can loop on those as well.  MIght be easier.  There are several ways to do this, but this is getting a long way from you question - look for simplifying your architecture to make this work :)

Comment: Yes, I try to limit the number of training in relation to payment ... I edited my first message because it was not precise enough. In fact, I do not have `fk_training` to the `Payment` table.

So, I think it's doesn't correct?? 

`$PaymentHasBeenMadeForThisTraining = Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student)  
    ->where('fk_training', $request->get('fk_training')) 
    ->first();  `

Comment: OK, all good.  If you are trying to limit the number of training related to payments, then this answer will work for you.  But you will need to get the FKs correct on the models.  You will need to add `fk_training` to the **Payment** table.  You need to remove `fk_payment` from the **Training** model.  **Training** will pick up payments from the foreign key on the **Payment** model.  The relationships won't work with your current DB structure.  The **Payment** model should have ONE training (thus the FK is on the **Payment** model).  You won't be able to limit using your current DB FKs

Comment: I modified, when I add a recording on the table 'training', I have a message 'duplicate' even if there is no recording ... What did not I follow ??? I edited my first message with all my code... Thank you Watercayman.

Comment: In the function `public function payments () {return $ this-> hasMany ("App \ Payment", 'your_foreign_key', 'your_local_key');
}` you also have `return $ this-> hasMany ("App \ Payment", 'fk_training', 'id');` it's correct ?

Comment: You've got a lot of changes here.  A lot of work to change the DB.  I strongly recommend testing this on its own first rather than trying to see if this works in that huge method.  So - write your methods for  `payments()` and `training()` and test these first to make sure the relationships work - this will tell you if your methods & FKs are correct. Then, remove ALL of the conflict checks in your `store()` method and JUST test to see if the payment has been made for the training.  Get that working, and *then* build in the other stuff.  Right now, getting 'duplicate' is confusing the task :)

Comment: my relationships seem to be ok, I made you a screenshot.
We are in the Controller Training ???

Comment: Remove `$trainings = Training::with('payments')->get();`.  This gives us a collection every time and will almost always be set.  The other two queries are two ways of doing similar things, as I said in my answer.  Depending on what you are after, use one or the other.  The 'Limit !' message is telling you that you have mostly solved this issue.  That if-check tells you that the student from the form *has paid for SOME trainings*.  In that variable (`$johns`), you now have a collection of all trainings he has paid for.  Now check if fk_training from form is in that collection, and if so, paid!

Comment: I still have the same problem, it is impossible to add recordings ...

In fact, my goal is that  if a student has paid for 2 trainings. I can not add a third training. I must have a message informing me that I have exceeded the authorized limit.

Comment: That's a different problem.  But easy to solve.  `if( count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= 2) { limit }`.  FIrst problem - if impossible to add trainings, have they already paid for this specific training?  If so, the code is working correctly.  Remember, the query above checks to see if they have paid for this specific training (from the form).  This ties it directly to that training - you don't want them to pay for the exact same training twice, so this query will determine that for you.  If they are trying to pay for a different training, no match, and it should allow.

Comment: Yeess, it works ahahahha thank you! Now, if I want to replace the value `2` bij `number_seance ` of my table 'payment' it's possible?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  that's a totally different query / question / goal, I think.  I THINK you are already doing this.  Because the new `fk_training` on the **Payment** model is linking THIS payment to THAT training, the query above should tell you if that particular training has been paid for. I don't know exactly what number_seance is for, but doesn't `fk_training` take its place and make that work?  If it is counting the number of payments - that's not going to work - the above `count()` will do that FOR 1 TRAINING. `Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student)->count()` will give you total

Comment: the `number_seance` variable calculates the  number seance and returns the total in the table payment

Your code works purpose, except that it is not related to number_seance
`if (count ($ thisStudentsTrainings)> = 2)`

If I have 3 seances for a student I have to modify it each time on the code ?? Il me faut la `fk_payment` to retrieve the number seance, I think???

Comment: Hmm.  `$total = Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student)->get()` gives you TOTAL payment **objects** for this student.   `$one = Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student)->where('fk_training', $fk_training)->get()` gives the payment **object** for this student for ONE training, but this should never be more than one - why would they pay twice for same training?  Payment $ for this training: `$one->total`.  Sum $ of all payments for all training ever for this student: `$total->sum('total')` .

Comment: I have difficulty with my english sorry ...
I do not have a problem with my total variable ...

I want to link the number_seance to `if (count ($ thisStudentsTrainings)> = 2) {`

so I will have this ???  `if (count ($ thisStudentsTrainings)> = number_seance) {`  the number_seance comes from the table payment

Comment: I don't really understand what `number_seance` is, or how it is attached to the payment.  Is this the fk of the training?  If so, this is already handled in the query to get `PaymentHasBeenMadeForThisTraining`, which is another way to query to see if this has been paid for.  I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. From your question, I thought you were trying to see if a payment has been made against a training, and if so stop them from paying twice.  I don't know what you are asking for with the payment field `number_seance`, but I think this is not same as orig. question?

Comment: No, number_seance is fk_payment (normally) when I fill in the fields of the payment form. I must add the number seance. For example, I want 4 seances.

In my form 'Training' I add  the dates of seances, I can add normally that 4 seances, you follow me?
How do I create this check ??? Because, there is no limit of recordings ... It's a problem

Comment: I think I follow now.  This is why we changed the architecture, you used to be able to make a payment object with unlimited trainings.  Now, there is **one** training for each payment.  Because Payment has one FK (`fk_training`), you can not make multiple trainings on a single payment.  The `number_seance` field should be removed from the Payment model, it can never be more than 1.  Now, a person creates a payment for a training.  To limit from paying for same training twice, that's what `$hasPaidForThisTraining` was for.  **Create a new payment every time** and you can check from that var.

Comment: we could not try another day with number_seance? I absolutely have to compare the number of seances with the training allowed. I thanks very much for the time you have devoted to me Watercayman for this post.

Comment: Yes, you can.  But use the relationship to check, rather than a field on the payment.  You can do this several ways, but if you are looking for a specific person's number of seances, use `$thisStudentsTrainings` query above.  If you want it for the specific date, add the `whereDate` clauses in.  I think your architecture is now much better for this, but you will have to play with it to get exactly what you need.  sorry I can't help give you exact code :(

Comment: no worries, you helped me a lot. Thank you a lot. Nice evening